# Converting associative array string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I've been trying to convert an associative array string but I can't seem to make it work.

I've tried the code below but it is not working.

```
var string = "{'custom_text_record': 'Text Here', 'fill_record': '0'}";
var s_obj = JSON.parse(string) ;

alert(s_obj['custom_text_record']);
```

Comment: The given string is an invalid JSON. It should use double quotes both for key and value. Also, that's not an associative array (it doesn't exists in JavaScript), but an object.

Comment: @EliasSoares an associative array is any data type that uses key / value pairs. By that definition, a JavaScript object _is_ an associative array. `Map` and `WeakMap` are other examples, so associative arrays _do_ exist in JavaScript.

Comment: @PhilGreene Instead of declaring a string and parsing it, just use an object literal: `var s_obj = { custom_text_record: 'Text Here', fill_record: '0' }; alert(s_obj.custom_text_record);`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree to your POV, but that might confuse people that are used to use associative arrays in other languages like PHP where it's defined like an array itself and not as an object, map or weakmap. Objects are not arrays in javascript, they properties and methods are different. That's why I prefer not calling it associative array

Answer (score 3):

You need to basically get **JSON format** from the associative array string,

The JSON format should be "{'custom_text_record': 'TextHere','fill_record':'0'}" before we use **JSON parse** function

Please try this.

```js
var string = '{"custom_text_record": "Text Here", "fill_record": "0"}';

var jsonStrig = '{';
  var items = string.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var current = items[i].split(':');
    jsonStrig += '"' + current[0].replace(/{|'|"|}|\s/g, '') + '":"' + 
                 current[1].replace(/{|'|"|}|\s/g, '') + '",';
  }
  jsonStrig = jsonStrig.substr(0, jsonStrig.length - 1);
  jsonStrig += '}';

var s_obj = JSON.parse(jsonStrig);
console.log(s_obj['custom_text_record']);
```

Regex might be used to filter the single quote,  double quote, and bracket, spaces which can appear in the associative array string.
I think we can convert any type of associative array string like **'{ key : value }' style** into the correct **JSON format** and finally get **an array** in this way.
I hope this would be helpful.